# Stop scheduleAtFixedRate to schedule new tasks, until the current one is done

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have this piece of code

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Runnable runnable = () -> {

        if(i.get() < 5){
            try{ Thread.sleep(2_000); }catch(Exception ignored){ }
        }else if(i.get() >= 15){
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println(i.getAndIncrement() + " - " + stpe.getQueue().size() + " - " + LocalDateTime.now());

    };

    ScheduledFuture<?> sf = stpe.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Thread(runnable, "Testing"), 0, 1_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

The console after execution:

```
 0 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:04.865501800
 1 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:06.886657500
 2 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:08.890066
 3 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:10.894186200
 4 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:12.898171
 5 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:12.899077100 <---
 6 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:12.899077100 <---
 7 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:12.900068700 <---
 8 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:12.900068700 <---
 9 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:12.900068700 <---
10 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:12.901073800 <---
11 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:13.857069500
12 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:14.852331500
13 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:15.860971200
14 - 0 - 2023-03-27T13:40:16.865873300
```

As you can observe, I have a `Thred.sleep(2_000)` for first 5 executions, and after I am letting them to execute at the rate of ScheduledFuture until 15th execution which is stopping the program.

I know that `scheduleAtFixedRate` is not starting a new execution until the current one is finished.

But instead, is adding them in a waiting queue, from where is taking one by one and execute without respecting the rate.

As you can see from 5 to 10, are at same second like 4. Executions 5-10 were in waiting queue and executed them one by one without a rate. The difference between them, as time, is only the execution time.

After the waiting queue was freed, it continued from 11 to 14 at the rate.

How I can avoid 5-10 executions to be one by one instantly, but instead to be executed at a fixed rate(~1_000 ms)? I can find this waiting queue and to free it?

I want the time between the end of the task0 and the start of task1 to be 1s - task0_execution_time(like how is doing scheduledAtFixedRate), but to not have that waiting queue which can accumulate tasks.

For example:

1. start task1 with execution time 5s.
2. start task2 without pause(1s - 5s = -4s => instant start).
3. start task3 at 1s - task2_execution_time.

And to NOT accumulate task2 and task3 in a waiting queue and execute them instantly later, just because the task1 has execution time 5s, and task2 and task3 were scheduled to start during this 5s

Comment: Please explain what behaviour you want.

Comment: @tgdavies, I want the executions 5-10 to be executed at fixed rate(~1000ms, between them), not one by one instantly.

Comment: Have you thought about using `scheduleWithFixedDelay`?

Comment: @tgdavies the think which is bothering me at `fixedDelay` is that it's summing the delay and sleep. In my case, the threads which have `Thread.sleep` are executed at a distance of 3 seconds.

Comment: So you want the minimum time between the start of consecutive invocations to be 1000ms, and the minimum time between the end of one invocation and the start of the next to be 0ms?

Comment: @tgdavies, Yes. I want the time between the end of the task0 and start of task1 to be `1s - task0_execution_time` (like how is doing `scheduledAtFixedRate`), but to not have that waiting queue which can accumulate tasks. For example: I start task1 with execution time 5s. After start task2 without pause(1s - 5s = -4s => instant start). After task2, to start task3 at 1s - task2_execution_time. And to NOT accumulate task2 and task3 in a waiting queue and execute them instantly later, just because the task1 has execution time 5s, and task2 and task3 were scheduled to start during this 5s.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use an executor at all. A simple for loop with a variable `sleep` does exactly what you want:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long previousStartTime;
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
            previousStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(LocalTime.now().toString() + " doing task " + i);
            Thread.sleep(i < 5 ? 2000: 0);
            long taskTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - previousStartTime;
            System.out.println("   Task took " + taskTime);
            long timeToWait = Math.max(0L, 1000L - taskTime);
            System.out.println("   Waiting " + timeToWait);
            Thread.sleep(timeToWait);
        }
    }
}
```

The thread uses `Thread.sleep(timeToWait);` to wait for the correct interval before performing the task again. If instead you wrote:

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < previousStartTime+timeToWait) {
  // do nothing
}
```

That would be "busy waiting", and would consume CPU resources.

Comment: In reality I execute it at infinitely, not just 15 times, and the `Thread.sleep` is in random tasks, depends by the data from that moment. And in this case appears busy waiting.

Comment: There's no busy waiting. You can of course make this an infinite loop rather than a for loop.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I know what `sleep` in a loop is always busy-waiting.

Comment: Maybe you are :-)

Comment: Can you, please, to explain me why this case is not busy-wait?

Comment: Because the thread does a single `sleep` while its waiting to perform the task again. It isn't using any CPU resources during this time.